# Chart.js, Javascript, unable to sum a data set. Javascript return NaN and I am not sure why

Tags: javascript, chart.js

let me say I am extremely new to javascript and chart.js but I have been on a mission to learn. I finally come around to a problem. I have a pie/doughnut chart and I want to have the percentage on the chart. So I am summing up the dataset values then dividing the current value by that sum to get the percentage. my code is throwing a NaN and I am sure this is to do with my data. but I am really not sure how to debug this.

I have 3 files. a data2.php file that connects to MySQL and pulls the data. I will include it below with a sample of the average data it pulls. then I have my app3.js that has my jquery to pull data from the PHP file. it's the formatter function that I am having issues with. I did borrow this code from somewhere else on the net but I really want to try and understand how I can debug this code to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="chart-container">
    <h4>Turnover YTD Share</h4>
        <canvas id="ytdpie"></canvas>
    </div>

    <!-- javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

then here is my data2.PHP output

[{"Name":"shop1","Turnover":"131752.56","TransDate":"2018"},{"Name":"shop2","Turnover":"137962.93","TransDate":"2018"},{"Name":"shop3","Turnover":"221743.78","TransDate":"2018"},{"Name":"shop4","Turnover":"194462.63","TransDate":"2018"},{"Name":"shop5","Turnover":"334374.19","TransDate":"2018"},{"Name":"shop6","Turnover":"274830.83","TransDate":"2018"},{"Name":"shop7","Turnover":"322485.53","TransDate":"2018"},{"Name":"shop8","Turnover":"213896.70","TransDate":"2018"},{"Name":"shop9","Turnover":"151293.13","TransDate":"2018"},{"Name":"shop10","Turnover":"305464.83","TransDate":"2018"}]

and finally my app3.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "data2.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var Name = [];
        var Turnover = [];

        for(var i in data) {
            Name.push(data[i].Name);
            Turnover.push(data[i].Turnover);
        }

        var chartdata = {
            labels: Name,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: 'Turnover YTD',
                    //backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(191, 66, 66, 0.4)',
            'rgba(191, 127, 63, 0.4)',
            'rgba(191, 191, 63, 0.4)',
            'rgba(127, 191, 63, 0.4)',
            'rgba(63, 191, 63, 0.4)',
            'rgba(63, 159, 127, 0.4)',
            'rgba(63, 191, 191, 0.4)',
            'rgba(63, 127, 191, 0.4)',
            'rgba(63, 63, 191, 0.4)',
            'rgba(127, 63, 191, 0.4)',
        ],
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: Turnover
                }
            ]
        };
var options = {
maintainAspectRatio: true,
legend: {
    display: true
},
plugins: {
              datalabels: {
            formatter: (value, ctx) => {

     let datasets = ctx.chart.data.datasets;

     if (datasets.indexOf(ctx.dataset) === datasets.length - 1) {
       let sum = datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
       let percentage = Math.round((value / sum) * 100) + '%';
       return percentage;
     } else {
       return percentage;
     }
   },
            color: '#000',
                 }
  },

 };
        var ctx = $("#ytdpie");

        var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: chartdata,
            options: options


        });
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
   });

   });
```

So I am almost certain it's the way I am calling my dataset in the function but I don't understand this code well enough to be sure what I am doing wrong. most examples I look at I feel like this should work.

```
   formatter: (value, ctx) => {

     let datasets = ctx.chart.data.datasets;

     if (datasets.indexOf(ctx.dataset) === datasets.length - 1) {
       let sum = datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
       let percentage = Math.round((value / sum) * 100) + '%';
       return percentage;
     } else {
       return percentage;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Your `Turnover` values are **strings**, not numbers. You can use `+` or `Number()` to force them to be interpreted as numbers.

Comment: replace: let sum = datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
with:        let sum = datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b) , 0);

Comment: Like @Pointy mentioned it, your numbers are strings, I would like to add parseInt function for this - parseInt(str);

Comment: @CommunityIsridiculous well no, not `parseInt()`, because the numbers have fractional parts. The `parseFloat()` function would work, as well as the `Number()` constructor or the `+` unary operator.

Comment: @Margon that worked perfectly! thank you very much. Now I am looking at it it's completely obvious. Learning a new language always blinds you the obvious stuff!

Comment: I'd also suggest to check [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_mistakes.asp)
 and [this one](https://charlieharvey.org.uk/page/javascript_the_weird_parts) for much more kinky js stuff @LanceRussell

Comment: @Margon  will do buddy. thank you again.

Comment: @Pointy oh ye, you are right, All ways mix them up since I usually use Number() if I need too aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @Pointy for highlighting I was trying to sum a string. and then for @Margon for showing me how to correctly format my line of code.

replaced: sum = datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); with: sum = datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b) , 0);

and that has solved my issues. Thank you all for the help.